# Unable to build Hyper - invalid character `-` in crate name

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, hyper, rust-obsolete

I am trying to run the hyper example listed on the Github readme.

```
extern crate hyper;

use std::io::Write;

use hyper::Server;
use hyper::server::Request;
use hyper::server::Response;
use hyper::net::Fresh;

fn hello(_: Request, res: Response<Fresh>) {
    let mut res = res.start().unwrap();
    res.write_all(b"Hello World!").unwrap();
    res.end().unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    Server::http(hello).listen("127.0.0.1:3000").unwrap();
}
```

And the Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
[package]

name = <crate_name>
version = <version>
authors = <authors>

[dependencies]
hyper = "0.3"
```

However, when I attempt to build it using Cargo run I get the following error:

```
error: invalid character `-` in crate name: `build-script-build`
error: invalid character `-` in crate name: `pkg-config`
error: invalid character `-` in crate name: `rustc-serialize`
```

I looked through these different crates trying to see if maybe I could just change a "rustc-serialize" to "rustc_serialize" because I think that crate names can no longer have hyphens. However, I couldn't find anything of the sort. I would really like to be able to solve this problem because I have a feeling that I am going to run into this error a few more times while Rust is still being polished.

Edit: The versions are as follows:
Rust: 1.0.0-beta.2
Hyper: 0.3.14
Cargo: 0.0.1-pre-nightly (built 2015-03-09)

Comment: Please include relevant version numbers, e.g., for rustc and Cargo. Without those, it's impossible to give any specific advice.

Comment: Could you include the date in the cargo version number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version of Hyper seems to require a newer version of Rust, which automatically converts hyphens to underscores in crate names.

See [RFC 940](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/940) and [Issue #23533](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23533).

Comment: So I should be able to specify an older version of hyper and have this problem go away? Is there a way to determine what version of Rust a crate is expecting? P.s. thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Theoretically, this might work. There is no direct mention of what rustc build those crates work with. You might find something in the git commit history or in the issues on the Github page, though. (There was a new beta release yesterday, by the way.)